# how to use triggers when comparing two data from different tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CONSTRAINT (Movie.Date – person.DateOfBirth >= Movie.MinAge)
```

I am trying to  use triggers for this constraint, I am not sure how to use triggers when you are comparing  different data from different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.. I didn't test it!!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_movie_parent_rating
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF DateOfBirth ON Person
REFERENCING NEW AS n                 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   v_allowed VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
        SELECT CASE WHEN (Movie.Date - person.DateOfBirth  >= Movie.MinAge)
                    THEN 'Y'
                    ELSE 'N'
                END As Allowed
        INTO v_allowed 
        FROM Movie , Person
        WHERE Movie.id = :n.movieId
        AND Person.movieId = Movie.id
        AND Person.id = :n.id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      v_allowed := NULL;
   END;

   IF v_allowed IS NULL THEN
      Raise_application_error(-20202, 'Movie Detail not available in parent');
   ELSIF v_allowed = 'N' THEN
      Raise_application_error(-20201, 'Movie Restricted for User');
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: is Person.id = person.personid and Movie.id = movie.Movieid?         END As Allowed
        INTO v_allowed 
        FROM Movie , Person
        WHERE Movie.id = :n.movieId
        AND Person.movieId = Movie.id
        AND Person.id = :n.id;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      v_allowed := NULL;
   END;

Comment: I assumed the Join conditions! You can first confirm your query and fit into this.

Comment: Will this do FROM Movie , Person
        WHERE Movie.Movieid = :n.movieId
        AND Person.movieId = Movie.Personid
        AND Person.personid = :n.personid;

Comment: Yup,Looks fine. It must be a returning single row

Comment: it says  bad bind variable 'N.MovieID" when i run it

Comment: `MovieId` is a valid column name in `Person` ?

Comment: no it's  in the Movie table not the person table.

Comment: Okay.. that's the Problem.. We write trigger for `Persons` table and hence `:n` holds only Person's columns

Comment: oh right i fixed that now i get Error(29,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     ;

Comment: Unfortanetly ,I missed a semi colon in Final `END IF`

Comment: I think there is semi colon but it's not working. Here is the final line of syntax       Raise_application_error(-20201, 'Race Restricted for Horse');
   END IF
END;
/

Comment: `Raise_application_error(-20201, 'Race Restricted for Horse'); END IF; END; /`

Comment: Now i get Error(28,17): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.

Comment: Removing it...? does it work?

Comment: When i removed it i got 9 errors, The triggers that i am doing it for for this constraint (Race.RaceDate - Horse.DateOfBirth  >= Race.MinAge) but the one we did it should be similar i don't know why it's not working, each Race and horse has their on id(RAceID and HorseId).

Comment: ok I have sent it on email, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will avoid the mutating table error that arises when you select from a table within a row level trigger defined against the same table.

You should check the constraint whenever any involved table is changed.

Ideally, there should also be serialisation locks at within the trigger to ensure transactions executing concurrently do not alter the data in such a way as to break the constraint. This can be achieved by using modules within the supplied DBMS_LOCK package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Movie_Check_Age
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF <Join_Columns>, Date, MinAge ON Movie
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR csrPersons
  IS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM Person p
    WHERE p.<Join_Columns> = :new.<Join_Columns>
    AND   (Months_Between(:new.Date, p.DateOfBirth) / 12) < :new.MinAge;
  rPerson csrPersons%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN csrPersons;
  FETCH csrPersons INTO rPerson;
  IF csrPersons%FOUND THEN
    CLOSE csrPersons;
    Raise_Application_Error(-20001, 'Person too young to see movie');
  ELSE
    CLOSE csrPersons;
  END IF;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Person_Check_Age
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF <Join_Columns>, DateOfBirth ON Person
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR csrMovies
  IS
    SELECT NULL
    FROM Movie m
    WHERE m.<Join_Columns> = :new.<Join_Columns>
    WHERE (Months_Between(m.Date, :new.DateOfBirth) / 12) < m.MinAge;
  rMovie csrMovies%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN csrMovies;
  FETCH csrMovies INTO rMovie;
  IF csrMovies%FOUND THEN
    CLOSE csrMovies;
    Raise_Application_Error(-20001, 'Person too young to see movie');
  ELSE
    CLOSE csrMovies;
  END IF;
END;
/
```